# Force Close When Trying to Switch Activities

Tags: android

im trying to use a button to switch activities in my app, but it keeps force closing. Heres my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.idiedastyear"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".tabView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tab_view" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".calculator"
        android:label="Calculator"  >
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is the activity that has the button:

```
    package com.idiedastyear;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;


public class tabView extends Activity {

    Button calculator;

    @Override



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_view);
        calculator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculatorButton);

        calculator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent calculatorIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), calculator.class);
                startActivityForResult(calculatorIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }




}
```

If anyone could help it would be great! Thanks!

EDIT [Logcat]:

> 07-06 17:38:06.683: D/memalloc(25668): ion: Mapped buffer
>   base:0x5ce6c000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:53 07-06 17:38:08.885:
>   D/memalloc(25668): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d304000 size:3768320
>   offset:0 fd:60 07-06 17:38:08.985: D/CLIPBOARD(25668): Hide Clipboard
>   dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... ! 07-06
>   17:38:11.738: D/memalloc(25668): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d69c000
>   size:3768320 offset:0 fd:63 07-06 17:38:12.168:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(25668): Shutting down VM 07-06 17:38:12.168:
>   W/dalvikvm(25668): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40c72a68) 07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.idiedastyear/com.idiedastyear.calculator}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error
>   inflating class Textview 07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-06 17:38:12.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-06 17:38:12.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-06 17:38:12.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25668): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Textview 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   com.idiedastyear.calculator.onCreate(calculator.java:20) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  ... 11 more 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Textview 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552) 07-06
>   17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
>   07-06 17:38:12.178: E/AndroidRuntime(25668):  ... 21 more

Comment: Do you have a class called `calculator`? Because right now, you're trying to start an `Activity` from your `Button`'s class, which won't work. Additionally, when you get a force close, please post your LogCat logs.

Comment: Why don't you post some Logcat output.

Comment: try `Intent calculatorIntent = new Intent(tabView.this, calculator.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following:

`Intent calculatorIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), calculator.class);`

The second parameter is supposed to be the Activity Class name. You also seem to have mixed up the calculator instance name with the calculator.class here that you are launching.

I suggest the following:

1. Create an Activity class called CalculatorActivity.
2. Ensure that you have defined that in the AndroidManifest.xml
3. Use the following line to launch the Activity:

`Intent calculatorIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CalculatorActivity.class);`

Additionally to help you precisely, please provide the LogCat output also.

Comment: This can not be the case @ Romin. You can not write buttonObject.class.. it could be compiler error instead.

Comment: @Ankit I do not understand your point. Could you point out where have I used buttonObject.class in the above steps that I have given (1,2,3)?

Comment: The second parameter is supposed to be the Activity Class name. You also seem to have mixed up the calculator(Basically it is a Button instalce) instance name with the calculator.class here that you are launching.,, I don't see this mixed up of names can be a cause of the problem. Although it is a good suggestion..

Comment: The first line in my answer was how the code was written earlier and which I told to change. My answer clearly states that the second parameter is something like CalculatorActivity.class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use

```
 startActivityForResult(calculatorIntent, 0);
```

instead of above use

```
startActivity(calculatorIntent);
```

startActivityForResult(calculatorIntent, 0);
 is use to have result from the activity you are starting. if youjust want to switch activity startActivity is suffiecient. Although you should post logcat for better answers.

Comment: from the logcat it can be assumed there is a problem in you calculator class,  Please post calculator oncreate and xml file also